# Glow effect invisible on transparent background

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, blur

I'm trying to render a lightsaber on a transparent background to use as game sprites. I've followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0aDc9NAUjo) on youtube to create the glow/blur effect and it worked great on a black background but it's completely invisible on a transparent background.
I figured I had to put an alpha channel node somewhere to make it work but I tried all the "alpha" named nodes all over the place and without success.

This is how the node setup looks like
[image: compositor nodes]

Here is the **[blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0y4s33tsjdby7dy/red_lightsaber.blend?dl=0)** if you want to take a closer look.

EDIT: Found a solution/workaround. Doesn't look as good as before but it's close enough.

[image: compositor nodes]

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Answers/solutions belong in the [answer section below](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), please avoid putting them in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

There is a fundamental problem with glows. **Glow cannot be merged into a composite with alpha**, because such layer is then composited using the **'mix/normal'** color operation. What you need is having the glow **separate** and combine it with **add/dodge**. Here is the explanation:

[image]

If the *Glow layer* (foreground) is lighter than *Background*, the Normal/Mix color operation with alpha will not be as bright as original Add operation with alpha. If the Background is lighter than the glow (a color glow on white) - the end result will be **darker** than *Background* leaving unwanted effect!

That's why you **never ever ever** composite color glows into a single merged layer with alpha that's supposed to be overlayed with Mix/Normal mode over some other than complete black background.

---

Now let's say you have object with a color glow on **black** background and you need to make this background transparent. Here is how you correctly do it:

[image]

You break down the image into channels and use each channel as alpha for a solid red green and blue - what this is is **separating** the background **per channel**. As it is black the alpha of the background is 0. You then add the colored channels with alpha together to reconstruct the image. Simple.

With nodes when adding the channels together turn *Include alpha of second input* on:

[image]

Comment: wow! What's a good resource to learn all this?

Comment: @cegaton I learned this trick by reverse-engineering Photoshop color actions a while ago, I believe it was this action: http://www.howtogeek.com/59634/remove-backgrounds-automatically-with-a-free-photoshop-action/

Comment: Not tested, but I think some kind of custom glow can be added to a rgba composite by inverting the channels, adding 3-5 different blur nodes, merging/mixing all blurs and inverting all again.

Comment: @poor to add glow you can just screen a blurred version of image over the original. It should work without the double invert.

Comment: Good post. So what is the correct way to composite color glows?

Comment: @Jerryno Mhh. Right, this also affects the alpha, but I'm not sure whether the result is satisfying :) Ok, I'll give it a try in the next days.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. Glows are perfectly well expressed using associated alpha. @Gez's answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44126/213 demonstrates. Remember, alpha formats are not identical, and that fire example is ridiculous simple using a properly generated associated alpha image. Associated alpha images represent both emission and occlusion, something that unassociated alpha images cannot.

Comment: @TroyJamesSobotka What is incorrect about this? When you have *multi-layer* format like .tiff or .exr and associated alphas (you can have how many you want!) that is *no composite*. I can export ID masks, multiple layers like this and what not and do wonders in compositor actually. Also many packages cannot do the *Alpha over* operation correctly (mostly game engines) and it's still best to export the transparent solid and then the transparent glow for add operation. The example with fire for extracting black background is totally correct - it will work on ridiculously complex images too.

Comment: @jerryno I completely agree that the general concept is a slave to the engine compositing alpha correctly. What I was taking issue with was the “never ever ever” for glows. Associated alpha works exactly as it should in this instance when setting alpha to zero and non zero RGB; it is an add. So indeed, you can composite fire, glows, halations, etc. with a standard alpha over. The issue is that unassociated alpha _can never_ express this very legitimate composite, which is why many consider associated alpha as the one-true-alpha.

Comment: This setup is both pointless and misleading:The ONLY thing achieved by this is to produce an associated plate with alpha=0 that cheats the broken Blender's viewer (that uses unassociated alpha) into showing the emission.
It would be exactly the same to just use a set alpha node and plug black to alpha, without all the channel separation/recombination stuff and plug it to an alpha over node.
Also, the exact same effect would achieved by a single add node.
It's just the viewer that is broken. Associated alpha should work straight away without all the fuss if the viewer worked properly.

Comment: Sadly it's still broken in 2.8. Same problem.

Comment: From what I know, and Alpha Over operation with A over B works like this:
1. Substract Alpha of A from RGB of B.
2. Add RGB of A to RGB of B.

In such case - a transparent (alpha=0), but emissive (R,G,B > 0) pixel should be perfectly reproduced with a simple Alpha Over operation.
There should be no need to separate the emissive and occlusive passes.
Something must be broken in Blender if that's the case.

Answer (score 10):

Alpha compositing with associated (often called "premultiplied") plates allows luminescent transparent pixels to be composited.
You just need to make sure that you are saving to a format that allows associated alpha (exr, for instance) and that the program that will do the compositing can interpret that alpha channel correctly (i.e. that it doesn't multiply the alpha channel to the foreground plate as part of the alpha over operation).

[image: This image shows how to produce a simple glow and save it as EXR]

[image: This image shows the resulting exr imported back in blender and composited over a gray background, keeping the glow]

Check this simple example. There's nothing strange to be done, just add the glow and save as EXR.
To check it's working, load the resulting image into the compositor, and do an alpha over on gray. You'll see the glow.
Notice that Blender's viewer is a bit broken and won't show the glow when you plug the viewer straight to the RGBA output of the loaded EXR, but the glow is there and will show with the alpha over operation.

Here's the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is strange that Blender's viewer isn't doing this right. I had a lot of trouble with compositing fire+smoke renders because of this.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem just mix original and blurred image with an alpha-over node.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

What I would personally do, is to use the Difference Key or Color Key node with the version with a black background. Both nodes provide the transparent color and b&w matte.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the nodes you mentioned but I could figure out how to use them. Sorry for being such a noob. I found a workaround in the meantime and got a decent enough result

Comment: Whatever works. Glad that you came up with something functional.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and found solution. The color nodes just don't handle alpha very well. You just need to go to converter nodes and use the separete and combine RGBA, then combine red with red, green with green, blue-blue and ALPHA with ALPHA ;D (I used the add node for this).

If you want to control the intensity of the glow you need to put a multiply node between the separate and combine RGBA. and to control all the multiply nodes at the same time add a single value node (you find it in add/input/value node.) connected to the second slot of the multipy node.

In my case I used the add node because I needed to put an input outside the node group.
I hope it helps.
[image]

Comment: I don't think this node setup is valid, you are adding the image over itself creating over-exposures. Also the complicated node network is nothing more than just a single Add color node.