# Rendering a semi transparent object on a transparent background

Tags: rendering, transparency

I have a problem rendering a sphere with a semi-transparent material on a transparent background.
When rendered in preview mode, the result is correct, the invisible parts of the sphere don't show up :

[image: Preview Render]

But when I calculate the final render, I only get a totally transparent image. 
When the transparency box in the Render Properties is unchecked, it works fine : the problem only occurs when the background transparency is enabled.
For the material, I used a noise texture linked to an emission shader which I added to a transparent one :

[image: Preview Render]

Would you have any idea where it comes from ?

Comment: If you can see your material in the viewport, but not on the rendered image, you are probably experiencing a limitation of the rendered image's viewport. It has a problem displaying semi transparent emissive pixesl with no occlusion. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824 Check your image using the RGB view, not the RGBA view. Chances are your material is correct but the viewer cannot display it.

Comment: Probably related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56950/transparent-image-different-in-viewport-than-render/56986#56986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding the shaders instead of mixing them. Therefore, the material is interpreted by Cycles as being 100% transparent, regardless of what else it is.

You can fix this by swapping out your **Add Shader** for a **Mix Shader** and plugging in your texture to the **Fac** value instead of the **Strength** of the **Emission** node.

[image]