# Add reflection to transparent cycles material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I'm fairly new to Blender (V2.79) so a little help will be greatly appreciated. Please see attached image as reference. I'm trying to get the same shine/light reflection (C) on my transparent plastic (A) as I have on the 'printed' plastic (B). Thanks in advance.

[image: Cycles Node setup & render result]

Comment: Why the Transparent shader at all? The leftmost Principled shader is set to 100% transparent so what is the reason for mixing it with the Transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mixing transparency and the Principled BSDF, you're defining a shader that can return either reflection, or transparency, but never both. (and since you have mix factor=0.8, it will give transparency 80% of the time). So you're making the reflections transparent along with everything else. To get your desired result, you want a shader that gives glossy reflection normally, but returns transparency to any rays the gloss doesn't catch. Two different ways you can do this:

1) Get rid of the transparent BSDF and its mix shader, just keep the Principled BSDF node for A. This will leave your glassy Principled BSDF as the only shader. Since this a refractive shader, you will need thickness on your bread bag mesh. You can use a solidify modifier to achieve this. See here if you also need the alpha channel: [Render Glass like materials with Alpha Channel to composite in external app](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77448/render-glass-like-materials-with-alpha-channel-to-composite-in-external-app/105034#105034)

2) If you don't want/need refraction and don't want to deal with adding thickness or messing with ways to get alpha, you can replace the first Transparent/Principled BSDF mix with the shader described here: [Render Glass like materials with Alpha Channel to composite in external app](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77448/render-glass-like-materials-with-alpha-channel-to-composite-in-external-app/105034#105034)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Thanks JtheNinja for your answer and help. I've managed to resolve my issue. For those interested, see my updated node setup. Added to this was JtheNinja's input regarding the Solidify Modifier.