# How to get transparent glass option under film?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, camera, shaders, glass

I saw a response to the question 
 "[Render Glass like materials with Alpha Channel to composite in external app](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77448/render-glass-like-materials-with-alpha-channel-to-composite-in-external-app)" that you can check a transparent glass option under film to make the background image visible through the object [image]

But I dont seem to have that option. I'm using v2.79 and cycles. This is what i see [image]

Comment: It is very clearly stated at the beginning of the linked answer.

Comment: I see that now Ramos. Thank you for responding

Answer (score 1):

Quote from linked answer:

> Newer builds of Cycles (post 2.79, currently available from the buildbot) include a native functionality for this

The functionality is not included in 2.79, but in builds made after the official 2.79 release.

If you're feeling adventurous, those builds can be found at https://builder.blender.org/download/

Note! Using non-released builds may corrupt your .blend-files and may also cause them to not work with officially released builds.