# render on a transparent background (volume is almost invisible)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, transparency

I ran into a problem. If I render on a transparent background, then the output volume is almost invisible.
[image]
As you can see, the fire after the render almost disappears. :(

That is, I try to get the result like on the left preview

In addition:
If I remove the transparency, everything becomes normal, but the point is to get a tank with a shot on a transparent background

[image]

Thank you in advance! If something is wrong, feel free to edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The problem was solved through the composer.
I found the answer in one of the old posts of one of the participants [Gez](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20594/gez).
In discussion: [Transparent Image different in viewport than render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56950/transparent-image-different-in-viewport-than-render/56986#56986)

Another pretty good solution, namely the “Attempt 1”. Thanks to the user [jozxyqk](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1713/jozxyqk)
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32964/63657
[image]