# Rendering gives me a black screen

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, render-layers

In the past this was due to still having an image strip within the Video Sequencer Editor, but this time that's no longer the case. I'm not sure what's happened to cause this, but whenever I try to render out a single image or an animation sequence, I just get a black screen for each render.
I'm trying to render out a lightning animation on a separate Render Layer, along with a background on another. The Output under Render is set to PNG. I'm not sure what I've changed to cause it to give me a black screen. :-\

[image]

Comment: Lightning on a transparent background is not going to work in PNG, you need a format that can do associated alpha. For a deeper explanation read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background/44148#44148 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/glow-effect-invisible-on-transparent-background and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background

Comment: I'm still confused with what I can do with the image I have. I've never even heard of or come across EXR files. How exactly am I going to sort out my image file?

Comment: Read both answers on this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56950/transparent-image-different-in-viewport-than-render/56986#56986

Comment: I tried replicating the node setup from one of those answers and I still got the same results. :(

Comment: Also, before adding an image, I was able to render out a quick animation of some lightning I'd made, and that did show. Now it doesn't, even if I remove the image. I've even tried loading up older saves and they no longer show if I do a quick animation, so something else must have gone wrong.