# Transparency from shader becomes white when exporting on transparent background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, shaders, transparency, render-passes

So first time actually posting a question here, but I just can't seem to find a solution.
So I made this fire ramp shader for a project I'm working on, and I want to have a transparent background for comp purposes. However, whenever I try to export using png the albedo details of the shader turns white when there's nothing behind it. I tried exporting it using OpenEXR as well, and that seemed to work for some reason. I don't want a 32bit image though, and would preferably keep it as a png.

Below is two images, one from blenders render window, and one exported using png with a solid background for better visualization of the problem.
[image]
[image]

I'm at a complete loss, so if anyone got a solution I would be grateful!

Comment: Hello :). I'm no expert, but I'm afraid PNG doesn't support both emissive *and* transparent pixels. EXR is the way in compositing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render semi-transparent volume with cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles), [Transparent Image different in viewport than render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/56950/78972),

Comment: Aah, well that's annoying, guess I'll have to find a suitable solution then ^^' 
But thanks a lot! now i at least know what the issue is :)

Comment: Also, thank you for such a quick response! I just couldn't seem to find anything on the topic, so I guess I just gotta get better at googling :)

Comment: No problem :). You probably want to google "premultiplied vs. straight alpha". The [Wikipedia page on Alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) is also helpful. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Just **use version 2.92**. the bug with associated alpha in the render viewer has been fixed. And yes, avoid using .png as a file format as it cannot handle associated alpha correctly and cannot have pixels that are emissive and transparent. EXR is the perfect format for what you want to do. Read: blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/…

Comment: @JachymMichal premultiplied and straight can be misleading terms,  Associated and unassociated alpha seem more appropriate. If you want to read further read troy_s '  Hitchiker's guide to digital color https://hg2dc.com/2020/08/26/question-25/

Comment: Thanks @susu , I'm no expert on this :)

Comment: @JachymMichal but you are way on your way to be one!

Comment: Thanks @susu ! I did manage to make a composite setup that allows me to use png with both transparent and emissive texture tho. But I might still look into the EXR format, just not a huge fan of the amount of post handling the EXR requires to get the same color look ^^'