# Sun Mesh with Corona - Alpha Transparency Affects Appearance

Tags: transparency

I have a Blender scene with a Sun mesh and a Corona mesh around it. The Sun mesh looks as intended when I render the image with no alpha (black background). However, when I try to render a transparent image, the Corona's appearance fades away. I need help understanding why this happens and how to preserve the intended look of the Sun and Corona in a saved transparent image (if, at all, possible). Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Upd: I added the project file.
The render engine is cycles, no compositing.

The blend file:
[image]

Render (viewport):
[image]

Transparent PNG:
[image]

Comment: Search “PNG” here. It’s a broken encoding.

Comment: There can be many reasons. Please answer atleast a few of the following questions. Which render engine? Can you provide the screenshot of your shader nodes as well? Have you done any compositing work? If yes can you also share a screenshot of those nodes as well? If it's possible best way is to share the file itself.(You can use blend-exchange for that)

Comment: Added the file and answered @Akshay2005 questions. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: I checked out your file. When I rendered out a PNG with transparency turned on, I had no issues. I was able to render a visible corona with the transparency as well. Mabye you had acidentally turned off the corona collection during the render. Please check again. If everything's ok and you are still facing the problem, check out what troy is saying about the broken encoding.

Comment: Did you save the rendered file as well? It breaks on save.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32900/how-to-properly-render-smoke-on-a-transparent-background https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222837/blender-does-not-set-the-alpha-channel-correctly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/glow-effect-invisible-on-transparent-background https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43977/composite-blur-effect-cut-off-at-edges-with-transparent-background

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have already been asked in various forms over time and already has a multiple answers, but you never acknowledged any of the existing posts. We are not sure if you aware of them but none of the described techniques fulfil your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, apologies for the inconvenience. Indeed, I didn't search for the similar issues here thoroughly, mainly because I was struggling with articulating a search request. Some of these titles refer to color desaturation or semi-transparent volume which didn't occur to me as a valid search request because my corona mesh is not a volume, nor did I think about it as a color desaturation issue. I thank you kindly for the links, they should probably help.