# Textured item loses color/alpha clip in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, transparency, lighting, color

I just got done with a really nice cycles render and composite. I love how it looks in the composite preview, but when I go to export/save it as a PNG with alpha, it loses a lot of the color, and some of the compositing effects too. It almost seems like its using the initial render as an alpha mask. This issue does not happen when I export without transparency. If I export with a solid background, the result is as expected. This is an issue for me, as Im using this as part of a larger art piece.
I am using cycles, and will leave *hopefully* relevant nodes in the screenshots below.[image][image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with rendered output files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272917/problem-with-rendered-output-files). That question has been closed as duplicate, but the topic has actually been asked dozens of times here, see not only the "duplicate" link there but also a few other questions linked in the answer there to read more about this problem.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43977/composite-blur-effect-cut-off-at-edges-with-transparent-background/44126#44126 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177022/glare-effect-transperancy-problem/177030#177030 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260675/glare-alpha-not-saved-to-png-file https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164895/rendering-with-a-luminous-outline-on-transparent-background/165275#165275

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263759/blender-result-different-from-png-rendered/263761#263761