# Point density halo particle system not rendering 'head on'

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

Rendered:
[image: rendered particles]

Refuses to render (Seemingly) outside of emitter:
[image: render with no particles]

Even when on a separate layer:
[image: just the particles]

There is a rendering 'domain' that is sufficiently sized (Since it renders in the first instance) and it's not range clipping related so I'm sort of stumped.

Comment: you say you are using halo particles, yet this is tagged with cycles. There are no halo particles in cycles. Are you using the blender internal renderer?

Comment: @David there are most definitely Halo particles in Cycles, since I'm using them and definitely using Cycles Render.

I mean I could take a screenshot if you really don't trust me, but I'm looking at 2 panels, one says "Cycles Render" and the other says "Halo".

Comment: If you are dealing with particles that are luminous but create no occlusion, the viewer for the rendered image cannot display them correctly in RGBA. The viewer is broken. It is likely that nothing is wrong with your setup. Try displaying the image using RBG only. See this related posts: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816

Comment: @cegaton No dice, unfortunately.

Comment: @Black--Snow Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: @Black--Snow right. sorry I forgot. So you are using the Point Density node and rendering the particles in a volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rendering issues seemed to be tied to how massive the scale of the project was (Needlessly, too).
Scaling down to 1:10 (The object is now 100m long, not 1km) seems to have fixed the issues with rendering particles at all angles.