# alpha over node is adding to the foreground artifact that is not in the background

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, transparency

i'm using blender 2.8 beta and i'm trying to conduct a test in which i make a lightsaber without volume for the haze so that the rendition isn't to long, so i used 2 view layers (used to be called render layers) one of the blade and one of everything else so that in the compositor i can change the blade color, and then blur it, and then use a alpha over node to use it for the background of the other view layer. yet it adds a green to the edge of the handle.[image: compositor[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiuS3.png)

i'm trying to get rid of the green artifact around the handle of the lightsaber. it is more clear with colors other then white around it but alpha is replaced with white on this site. on the compositer screenshot i gave shows more clearly the problem

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you clarify what your question is? Has it stands there no question mark in your post and it is not clear what you are asking. Please edit your question and use punctuation and paragraphs so it is more clear and we can help you.

Comment: The viewer is broken. If you use associated alpha, your glow should work absolutely fine, just display broken in the viewer. For a couple of great answers, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/glow-effect-invisible-on-transparent-background/44137#44137 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824

Comment: thanks that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, sorry.  This might help, might not: https://uvassociates.in/sites/default/files/resize/remote/c0631e46351ca76e7380488b072beb7f-400x312.png

It makes a mesh invisible and just renders the light from it.  It's an older version of Blender, so may not work.  GL