# How to remove black color and use as transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I have image which as black background and i want to remove the black background and use the image as transparent only color smoke.

[image]

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuNxX.jpg)

Comment: Does the base image have transparency?

Comment: @brockmann i want to remove the black background to make it transparent

Comment: @lemon i have attach the image above in questions its totally black without transparency . I want to remove it like photoshop we use screen option to remove black background.

Comment: you could use a b&w version of your image that you'd plug into a ColorRamp that you'd plug into a factor of a Mix shader that mixes the color version and a Transparent node, but you'll always have a grey zone

Comment: Just match the Image Texture's color shocket to the Mix Shader's Fac shocket instead of the Alpha. You can put a ColorRamp between them if you want to adjust it but it's not necessary.

Comment: I think the best result may be to process the image before using it in Blender. With Gimp for instance "color to alpha".

Comment: @FFeller i tried as suggested plug the image texture to mix shader face the transparency created bu the color disappeared.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vKpd40J, if that can help (done using Gimp>Layer>Transparency>Color to alpha)

Comment: Did you plug it also in the diffuse shader?

Comment: @FFeller perfect thanks. Can you plz drop the node as answer many be for others it can be helpful

Comment: Read this answer:  [Glow effect invisible on transparent background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43327/92768)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't necessarily use the Mix Shader with the alpha channel of the image. You can also use the color channel. So on the darker areas the first shader (Transparent) will dominate and on the lighter parts the second shader (Diffuse) will get a higher value. You can plug a ColorRamp before the Fac shocket to finetune the silhouette. Of course you can use images with white background, just swap the transparent and diffuse shaders.
[image]

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: If you use EEVEE you have to put the Blend Mode to Alpha Clip. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html

Comment: I was using Cycles. I thought it wasn't working because in viewport shading - rendered was not working, but the actual render by pressing F12 worked.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

For anyone that comes back, here's a simpler node setup. Just run the image texture's color output through a principled shader's alpha attribute. That's the quick and dirty way, but an added color ramp in between gets a much nicer result. With a bit of tweaking, this should allow you to make most images transparent.

Comment: yeah this works