# Rendering with a Luminous Outline on Transparent Background

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, transparency

I am trying to achieve such effect on transparent background:
[image: Desired result]

What I currently have:
[image: Current result]

Is it possible to get something like this rendered in blender? Or should I use Gimp to manually add my outline?

Comment: Found the solution in Gimp [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nHqYk3EPSU). Still wondering though how to recreate such effect in Blender.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Glow effect invisible on transparent background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/glow-effect-invisible-on-transparent-background)

Comment: Apparently they would, but it turns out that they mean a lot more of fiddling around. Gimp solution seems to be actually the quickest and gives decent results. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your render is black&white you can use this:

- Set object material with **Emission** shader.
- In Properties Editor > Render Tab > Film > enable Transparent

**Eevee**
—
Enable Properties Editor > Render Properties > **Bloom**.
To control blooming you can do it here or in compositor with RGB Curve node (or ColorRamp) to make effect stronger or lighter.

[image]

**Cycles**
—
In compositor add Filter > **Glare** node type **Ghosts** try with Treshold = 0

Output format - I had to switch into OpenEXR file format to keep glowing, glaring, blooming what ever to call this in saved render.

[image]

### Important

There is an issue with inconsistency of viewport render vs Render (F12) for years.
But also viewport is not showing the glowing here, but the only one thing that you have to do is to plug output also into **Alpha** socket. Or add **Set Alpha** node for the same effect.

Output format - PNG (RGBA) is OK here

For full colour render combined with glow or emissive materials (like fire) on transparent background see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164940/2214

For effect of coloured glow (like in your reference image) add ColorRamp node.