# Rendering animation with Cycles doesn't export the emission

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, emission

I have set up in the compositor window the nodes to for my object to have emission applied to it.
When it renders the animation (using Cycles),the emission is not included. I have googled and not found a solution for this problem I'm facing.

[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file? and tbh the render result looks like it has emission?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260675/glare-alpha-not-saved-to-png-file https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164895/rendering-with-a-luminous-outline-on-transparent-background/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222837/blender-does-not-set-the-alpha-channel-correctly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177022/glare-effect-transperancy-problem/177030#177030 and more https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=png%20glare

Comment: I guess what you mean is when you save the render with transparency it seems to have no emission, because the render result itself has as @Chris already remarked. The reasons for this are all given in the various links provided here. Just as a simple solution: never render your images with the glow combined with the image. Set _Mix_ in the _Glare_ node to 1 so it only outputs the glow. In Blender you can add it over the original image and control the amount with the factor. For use in other softwares where you want to keep the transparency, save the image without glow and the glow separately.

Comment: This is if you do not want to handle EXRs. Save the glow image with disabled alpha channel, i.e in the PNG options "RGB" instead of "RGBA" to have the glow on a black background. In software like Photoshop you can then add the glow to layers below. However, this does not work if you want to keep transparency on underlying layers because the black background replaces transparency. So in order to have a glow with transparent background, use the RGB channels as masks to fill empty layers with red, green and blue and add them together. A bit too complex for comments, but the question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PNG won't keep the effects that exist over transparency. You need to find a trick, a basic one would be to render your image over a black background:

[image]

Then use these images in your image or video software in a layer that will be over your background in *Add* mode:

[image]

Comment: Why not use a format that support transparent emission. Like EXR?

Comment: Here's the File: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=NgSlZMy3" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NgSlZMy3/)

I see what you mean moonboots, but my file has animation with Boolean, which reveals each object which has emission. Like airport runway lights which animate on off.

https://i0.wp.com/aerosavvy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Airport-Lighting-Featured-Image.jpg?fit=905%2C509&ssl=1

Comment: Hi there Leander, EXR doesn't come with alpha background: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmb5HRU1cUo

Comment: I couldn't make EXR work either, have you been able? @Leander

Comment: @blender breath so maybe you should mix the background directly in the Compositor?

Comment: Just did a test. [Both (PNG! and EXR) work just fine](https://imgur.com/a/EvwttSS). Are you viewing the images incorrectly maybe? Does GIMP possibly just not import the images correctly. (I confirmed the correct channel data in nuke and blender independently.)

Comment: @Leander it works in Blender, what does it give if you export and try to open with Photoshop, Krita, Da Vinci or whatever app? And if it works, what are the saving options?

Comment: Photoshop is mainly for image editing, photography or painting. So it will not show us only the RGB data, but combine it with the alpha. (Like premultiplication.) Choose "[As alpha Channel](https://imgur.com/a/OaWVsCD)" for the EXR when importing it into photoshop. Compositing Software (blender, nuke, natron, resolve) can show your r, g, b and a separately by default - I didn't change anything.

Comment: OK, thanks I'll note that, I can't test in DaVinci or Photoshop because I don't have them

Comment: @lLander, can you also please test to see if it works with After effects? Can you do a screen recording so I can see your export settings from Blender, and how it works in another software, how the emission is imported. Thanks.

Comment: @moonboots, unfortunately I need to export into another software as PNG alpha background. So Ill have to do a work around regarding the emission. Thank you.

Comment: @blender breath So have you tried the kind of trick I show?

Comment: Yes, thank you, it was the closest to getting a better result. I hope in the near future the developers could possibly find a solution for this issue, or maybe an add-on.