Compositing get's applied in viewport and render result window but not in the saved image file
I am currently playing around with eevee next in Blender 4.2 just added a bloom effect via this simple compositing setup (the result doesn't change whether the alpha sockets are connected or not):
in the viewport it looks like this:

and in the render result it looks like this:
But after saving the image as a png with 16 bit color depths and (in this particular case) 50% compression (I tried all kinds of values) it looks like no compositing was applied at all:
I already tried to add a file output node after the glare node but it produces the same result.
In the post-processing timeline, both compositing and sequencer are checked.
Results do not change when toggling Raytracing.
While writing this I came across this post (don't know if this is still relevant): Glare alpha not saved to png file
and tried this node setup which produces the same result as before:

I am pretty much out of ideas of what to try at this point, so any help is appreciated.

It’s PNG. PNG cannot encode alpha properly. Export to EXR instead. It will work.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222837/blender-does-not-set-the-alpha-channel-correctly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272917/transparent-emissive-objects-glow-effect-not-visible-in-rendered-output-files/272919#272919 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164895/rendering-with-a-luminous-outline-on-transparent-background/165275#165275
