# Why are particles barely visible when rendering transparent background?

Tags: rendering, particles, export, transparency, visibility

When I render a particle system with a black background it looks great. When I render that exact same animation with transparent background to composite it later in Premiere, it is barely visible and loses almost all of its colour. Why does this happen? And is there a way to fix this or work around it? Photos of the same render attached with and without transparent backgrounds. [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260675/glare-alpha-not-saved-to-png-file https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222837/blender-does-not-set-the-alpha-channel-correctly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177022/glare-effect-transperancy-problem/177030#177030 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173932/exr-color-difference-to-png